# Explain the output of -D rates in GNU find

Tags: linux, find, utilities

I did

```
~/pythonsource1/python2.6-2.6.5$ find -D rates . -type d
```

and got

```
Predicate success rates after completion:
[need type] -type d [0.4] [280/4350=0.0643678] -a [0.4] [280/4350=0.0643678] -print [1] [280/280=1]
```

What does the `[0.4]` indicate ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from the source code, the numbers in square brackets are the *a priori* estimated success rate for a given predicate.  That is, the first `[0.4]` is an estimate of the probability that the `-type d` will evaluate to true.  It may be used to determine the order in which the terms of the predicate are evaluated.  You can find more in `findutils-4.4.2/find/parser.c`, `findutils-4.4.2/find/tree.c` and `findutils-4.4.2/find/pred.c`.